# mystery wave: what to call it?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

> I recently stumbled on a useful periodic waveform, but I don't know what to call it. It's drawn in blue in the enclosed image, with a sine wave drawn in red for reference. Do you know what to properly call this wave?

[image: plot of mystery wave in blue, with sine wave in red for reference]

The most efficient way I've found to generate the wave is by offsetting each quadrant of a sine wave, as in the following C code. The even quadrants are displaced, while the odd quadrants are inverted and displaced.

```
double MysteryWave(double fPhase)
{
  double r = fmod(fPhase + 0.25, 1);
  double s = sin(r * PI * 2);
  if (r < 0.25)
    return s - 1;
  else if (r < 0.5)
    return 1 - s;
  else if (r < 0.75)
    return s + 1;
  else
    return -1 - s;
}
```

A wave that is very similar but NOT identical to my mystery wave can be generated via the arcsine of the cubed sine, rescaled to $[-1..1]$ by dividing by $\pi / 2$. In other words the following function is close but not quite the same:

```
2 * asin(pow(sin(fPhase * PI * 2), 3)) / PI
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, each quarter period of your waveform is an actual sine wave, displaced and possibly reflected?

Comment: Come up with a name that you like and use it. I don't think there is one already.

Comment: In what way is it useful?

Comment: What's the context where such a "useful" function appears ?

Comment: @victimofleisure just a funny curiosity: In this other question, the very last graph shows a waveform similar to yours getting smoother cycle by cycle. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431415/technique-for-predicting-attractor-capture-in-nonlinear-differential-equations

Answer (score 2):

This is a more direct formula: there are two symmetries happening there, so you need to play with the values assigned to each $\frac{\pi}{2}$ interval in order to retrieve the correct "mapping" (probably it can be simplified more):

> $$\sin{[x+\pi+[\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot(-1)^{\lfloor\frac{x}{\pi/2}\rfloor}]]}+(-1)^{\lfloor{x/\pi}\rfloor}$$

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sin(x%2Bpi%2B(pi%2F2*((-1)%5E(floor(x%2F(pi%2F2))))))%2B(-1)%5E(floor(x%2F(pi)))%20from%20-2pi%20to%202pi) if my calculations are correct it matches your waveform:

[image]